# Can I have multiple instances of the same Imprisonment effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The end of Imprisonment reads

> You can use a particular special component to create only one prison at a time. If you cast the spell again using the same component, the target of the first casting is immediately freed of it's binding.

Does this mean I can only ever have a single creature suspended in Minimus Containment or does this mean that I need to provide a separate gemstone for each target?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have the same effect twice if you provide two gemstones. If the other was the intended meaning, the description would refer to the effect (along the lines of "You can maintain each effect once." or "If you cast this spell again, you have to choose a different option each time.").

Comment: Reusable costly spell components (without *"which the spell consumes"* in the description) can be used to cast the spell over and over. **Imprisonment is an exception** (you need one component for each active prison regardless of type). This is where the confusion comes from.